# How to replace newline with space except when it's the only character in a row

Tags: bash, notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, text-formatting

I have some text like:

> from her patient
>    scrutiny
>   and judicious criticism.
>
> J.K.
>
> WASHINGTON, D.C.
>
> April, 1919.

And want to leave it like:

> from her patient scrutiny and judicious criticism.
>
> J.K.
>
> WASHINGTON, D.C.
>
> April, 1919.

How can I do it? I know you can replace newlines easily using the find & replace tool with `/r/n` but I don't know how to do this.

Some extra step: I also want to delete one newline if the previous line was empty and just had a newline character. Is that possible?

I don't know much about programming but I'm okay if I need to use bash or any Terminal tool to do this. However I hope I can use 4 cpu cores because the text file is really long.

Comment: One file or multiple? If it is one file, you cannot really parallel-process this. Please show what line ending characters your file uses. Is it `\r\n\r\n` for the double whitespace? Can the file be converted to Unix line endings?

Comment: It's one file sadly. But it's alright, I'll just leave it running then. The ending characters are always `\r\n` and also for the double whitespace (`\r\n\r\n`). I would prefer to have Windows line endings but it's alright anyway, I think it's going to be easy to change `\r` to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\S)\R(?=\S)`
- Replace with:   # a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\S)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a NON space character before
\R          # any kind of line break
(?=\S)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a NON space character after
```

**Result for given example:**

```
from her patient scrutiny and judicious criticism.

J.K.

WASHINGTON, D.C.

April, 1919.
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]